# How to add READ, NOTIFY property to a custom characteristic in Android BLE GATT Server?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am hosting a GATT server in the Nexus 9 (as a peripheral). I am able to implement a characteristic with Read property and Notify property separately. How to host a characteristics with Read and Notify property?

In the below code Read property is implemented:

```
final String  SERVICE_A = "0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
final String  CHAR_READ1 = "0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";




BluetoothGattService previousService =
          mGattServer.getService( UUID.fromString(SERVICE_A));

if(null != previousService)        
         mGattServer.removeService(previousService);



        BluetoothGattCharacteristic read1Characteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
          UUID.fromString(CHAR_READ1), 
          BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ,
          BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ
          );                 

read1Characteristic.setValue(read1Data.getBytes());
BluetoothGattService AService = new BluetoothGattService(
          UUID.fromString(SERVICE_A), 
          BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);


        AService.addCharacteristic(read1Characteristic);
```

full source code [here](http://gaiger-programming.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-as-bluetooth-low-energy.html)

Answer (score 2):

Those properties are bitwise, so you can do the following:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic read1Characteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
          UUID.fromString(CHAR_READ1), 
          BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
          BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ
          );
```